# Unix - Split line after 9th comma

Tags: unix, shell, awk, ksh

I writing a ksh shell script and  I have long comma separated string that I need to divide into separate lines only after the 9th comma. After the 9th comma, I want to remove that comma and make a new line:

For Example:
Initial String
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21
```

I know this is possible with awk but I am not so familiar with command. Can someone please provide how to do this

Thanks

Comment: `man awk` ? .. are you familiar with that command? : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ s='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21'

$ print "$s" | tr , '\n' | paste -d , - - - - - - - - - - | sed -e 's/,\+$//'
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21

$ print "$s" | tr , '\n' | xargs -n 10 echo | tr " " ,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
21
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf("%s", $i);
        if (i % 10 == 0 || i == NF)
            printf "\n";
        else
            printf ",";
    }
}' textfile
```

Explanation: `NF` is the number of fields. `$i` is the `i`'th field; the `$` is an operator in Awk, not a [sigil](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: I still don't grok awk. I think I never will; bit verbose, not? **Edit** also, running this on [my long input sample (under _Bonus_)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708587/unix-split-line-after-9th-comma/6708908#6708908) results in a 3rd line with 13 elements. Is something wrong?

Comment: ... oh ... and there's a trailing comma on the last line

Comment: @sehe: fixed the trailing comma.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat t.txt | xargs -d, -rn10 | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

<sub>Note: useless use of `cat` for clarity: this could be any process</sub>

Depending on your actual need, drop the `sed` step and get the output space delimited

### Bonus points:

Input (t.txt)

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21
22,23
24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
```

Output

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,14,15,16,17,18,19
20,21
22,23
24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31
32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50
```

If you want homogeneous line-filling, add paste:

> ***`paste -sd, t.txt`***`| xargs -d, -n10 | sed 's/ /,/g'`

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,14,15,16,17,18,19
20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39
40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49
50
```

Comment: $ cat t.txt | xargs -d, -rn10 | sed 's/ /,/g'
xargs: illegal option -- d
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]

Comment: Hmmm you're not having GNU xargs; you may try `gxargs` or find out whether GNU xargs is available under /opt/ or similar (usual on at least Solaris). I know some BSD have 'switchable' userlands so what version of `xargs` is found depends on your environment. [AIX has packages for GNU coreutils here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/index.html)